# Can Nodemailer automatically split large emails into multiple smaller emails when sending?

Tags: node.js, email, attachment, email-attachments, nodemailer

I'm developing an app that should send emails with a lot of attachments. Each attachment is ~1-3 MB.

Can Nodemailer automatically split large emails into multiple smaller emails when sending so that the size of each email with attachments will not exceed e.g. 25 MB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it can not. You can more or less precalculate the resulting email size yourself. Attachments are sent as base64 so if your file is 10MB in size then the resulting email would be 10/3*4 + few kilobytes of overhead. If the result seems too close to 25MB then split your file yourself and send multiple messages instead of one.